How to update the element of set
I have a set of damaged lines initially.
damagelines = {1,5,8,10,25} at time t = 1 second
at time t = 2 seconds one of the lines i.e. l = 5 is repaired by the repair crew. I have a variable that indicates the repair status of the damaged line i.e. rep[l][t]. if the value of this binary variable is one for the damaged line 5 at time t is 2 that means the line is repaired and we have to update the element of the damaged line set. Now the new set of damaged lines is {1,8,10,25} at time t = 2 seconds. Can you suggest me code in OPL Cplex that helps in updating the element of a set?

You can use remove
{int} damagelines1 = {1,5,8,10,25};
range lines=1..2;

{int} damagelines[lines];

execute
{
  for(i in damagelines1) for(j in lines) damagelines[j].add(i);
  damagelines[2].remove(5);
  writeln(damagelines);
}

gives
[{1 5 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25}]

and with regards to your comment, to remove an element use remove.
{int} Slot={1,2};
range  r=1..30;

{int} DamagedLines={2};

{int} D_S[Slot] ;

{int} D_S1 = {1,5,8,10,25} ;

execute
{
  for (j in Slot)for(var i in D_S1) D_S[j].add(i);
  writeln(D_S[1]);
}


int repairstatus[i in Slot][j in 1..30]=(i==2) && (j==5);

execute { 
for (var s in r)
 { for (var i in DamagedLines)
  { if (repairstatus[i][s] == 1) { D_S[i].remove(s); } } } 
  writeln(D_S);
  }

gives
{1 5 8 10 25} 
 [{1 5 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25}]

And
{int} Slot={1,2,3,4};
range  r=1..30;

{int} DamagedLines={2};

{int} D_S[Slot] ;

{int} D_S1 = {1,5,8,10,25} ;

execute
{
  for (j in Slot)for(var i in D_S1) D_S[j].add(i);
  writeln(D_S[1]);
}


int repairstatus[i in Slot][j in 1..30]=(i>=3) && (j==5);

execute { 
for (var s in r)
 { for (var i in Slot)
  { if (repairstatus[i][s] == 1) { D_S[i].remove(s); } } } 
  writeln(D_S);
  }

gives
{1 5 8 10 25}
 [{1 5 8 10 25} {1 5 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25}]


I have to update the element of the set based on the value of the binary variable rep[l][t]. If the value of the binary variable (rep[l][t]) is one for line l = 5 at time t = 2 seconds. Then the new set should be {1,8,10,25}. But you have not used this binary variable to update the element of the set.

{int} D_S[Time] ;                                                                                                              D_S[1] = {1,5,8,10,25};
execute {
for (var t in Time) {
for (var i in DamagedLines) {
if (rep[i][t] == 1) {
D_S[s] -= i;
}
}
}
}     I am writing the code in this way but it is not giving results. Kindly suggest me correct code.

suppose I have {int} Slot={1,2,3,4}; and the result I want is [{1 5 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25} {1 8 10 25}]. How do we code? So that we can remove that element (5) for t = 3, t=4, and t = 4
